# Using Partial Summation with an Infinite Sum

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm looking at a proof of Brun's theorem.

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{p  : p+2 \text{ is also prime}\}$.

Then we want to show that the sum $$\sum_{p\in \mathcal{P}} \frac{1}{p} < \infty .$$

The proof given just says "by partial summation." I'm comfortable using partial summation, but usually it would be with a sum over $p\leq x$ or something. I know we don't actually know if the set $\mathcal{P}$ is infinite (since that would be the twin prime conjecture), but it's the lack of an $x$ that's got me confused.

I was looking at either defining a multiplicative function 
$$a(n)= \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{if $n$ and $n+2$ are both prime}\ \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

and letting $f(n)=1/n$, then

$$\sum_{p\in \mathcal{P}} \frac{1}{p} = \sum_{n} a(n) f(n) .$$

I also thought about multiplying and dividing by $\log(p)$ (or both), but I'm still stuck with the lack of an $x$.

I don't need help with showing the series converges, it's specifically using partial summation on a sum of this kind that I need help with.

**Edit:**  For anyone interested, the proof was from An Introduction to Sieve Methods and Their Application by Alina Cojocaru and Ram Murty. I still don't know for sure what they intended, but I decided to impose a limit on $p$ and use partial summation over the sum of primes $p \leq x$, then let $x$ tend to infinity to get the result.

Comment: I am aware of Brun's theorem but not aware of its proof(s). Unless you provide a link or some details about the proof you are looking at, it's impossible to say what  it is saying about partial summation.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the proof is from An Introduction to Sieve Methods and their Applications by Cojocaru and Murty, but the proof just says "By partial summation," and then "apply theorem x," so I didn't think that would be much help.

Really I was hoping someone could tell me something about doing partial summation on sums of this form.

Comment: Well OK then, but  I don't know what they mean either.

Comment: It follows [by partial summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381966/divergence-of-reciprocal-of-sequence-knowing-the-asymptotic-density/2381986#2381986) from $\pi_2(x) = \sum_{[p ,p+2] \le x} 1 = \mathcal{O}(\frac{x}{\log^2 x})$ @DanielWainfleet