# Divergence of Reciprocal of Sequence knowing the Asymptotic Density

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In a paper, it is stated that if a particular sequence of positive integers $a_1<a_2<\dots$ satisfies that the number of $a_i$ which do not exceed $n$ is $o(\frac{n}{\log ^2(n)})$, then $\sum \frac{1}{a_i}$ converges. I cannot see why this would be true- it's probably really simple but it's evading me right now. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A(n) = \# \{ a_m \le n\}$ and use summation by parts $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_m}  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A(n)-A(n-1)}{n} =\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{A(N)}{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n)(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$$